# Excel file uploads stall in Liferay

Tags: liferay

We're using Liferay 7.3 and have added file upload to one of our Portlets.

Our file upload uses `UploadPortletRequest` in the usual manner; however we have been able to reproduce the problem when uploading to Liferay's built in document library.

When uploading an Excel file of 25MB, the UI hangs and the upload appears to never complete. Looking in the browser's network tools shows the bytes are all sent to the server, but the other end never seems to respond. Hitting refresh shows the upload did in fact complete.

We think Liferay is doing something with the uploaded file which gets stuck, but we can't work out what.

The exact same steps with a 25MB ZIP file work fine, suggesting an Excel-specific issue.

Comment: More details and code pls

Comment: Indeed, seconding Daniele: Consider "the usual manner" to be closed as "works for me". Please provide a [mcve] and the *exact* version. Also: Is it a function of the file size? Can you reproduce with certain file sizes, but not with others? Is it only a specific file?

Comment: @David North can you please check this property value in portal ? "Upload Servlet Request" path could be Control Panel -> Configuration -> System Settings -> Infrastructure.

Comment: is your file type extension is there in the allowed extension list?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the comments above, **we have been able to reproduce the problem when uploading to Liferay's built in document library** via Liferay's own admin interface - which is why I didn't bother to include a minimal reproduction in code.

The good news is that we have now diagnosed and fixed the problem.

Liferay attempts to perform full text indexing on most files placed in the Document Library. This means that a 25MB .xlsx file (which is of course much bigger when unzipped) will be read into memory and turned into a string. Which accounts for the horrendous TTFB on the upload request.

In `portal-ext.properties`, set the  `dl.file.indexing.ignore.extensions` property and include `.xlsx`. This avoids reading the whole file into memory and thus resolves the performance problem.

Note that the implementation means the `dl.file.indexing.max.size` setting is no use for this issue: the whole file is turned into a string in-memory, regardless of how big it is, before the max size setting is checked against it.